# Strange exception of Httpcore nio in java

Tags: java, nio

```
    Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.closeActiveChannels(AbstractIOReactor.java:532)
 at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.hardShutdown(AbstractIOReactor.java:564)
 at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.doShutdown(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:411)
 at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.execute(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:340)
 at com.***.clawer.Clawer$1.run(Clawer.java:81)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.IllegalStateException: I/O reactor has been shut down
 at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.DefaultConnectingIOReactor.connect(DefaultConnectingIOReactor.java:190)
 at com.***.clawer.Run.run(Run.java:29)
```

Comment: posting the code of yours that invokes this might be useful

Comment: I/O error: I/O dispatch worker terminated abnormally
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.IllegalStateException: I/O reactor has been shut down
 at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.DefaultConnectingIOReactor.connect(DefaultConnectingIOReactor.java:190)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a NIO Reactor that is closed by the time you try to use it ( connect to it )

See:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: I/O reactor has been shut down
```

Comment: Possible, but before that, a NullPointerException occurs during doShutdown.

Comment: I think the worker thread stopped caused this exception, but i do not know why.

Comment: @Thilo: Yes, during the shutdown, the method `AbstractIOReactor.closeActiveChannels` tries to close the reactor but it is null because that is already closed. That's the root cause.

Answer (score 1):

I had a look at the code, and I think that NPE is happening because `getSession()` is returning null.